# couchbase cbrestore fails to transfer data

Tags: couchbase

cbrestore runs without error messages, but does not transfer any data. 
[image]

The problem occurs on debian 10 with couchbase versions 6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.3. 
The exactly same command runs without problems on windows 10 with couchbase version 6.0.1 - with the same dump.

Comment: You may want to create a ticket on issues.couchbase.com